# Perl regular expression with "[]"

Tags: regex, perl

My data looks like:

```
NC_004415 NC_010199 ([T(trnH ,trnS1 trnL1 ,)])
NC_006131 NC_010199 ([T(trnH ,trnS1 trnL1 ,)])
NC_006355 NC_007231 ([T(trnM ,trnQ ,)])
```

I want to capture everything between `[]`:

```
while( my $line = <crex> )

 {  $t=$line=~m/(\[.*\])/;

    print $t;
 }
```

The output of `$t` is `1`. Why is it not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using a capturing group, you can just use `$1` after the match succeeds:

```
if($line =~ m/(\[.*\])/) {
    print $1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`$line =~ m/(\[.*\])/` returns a list of the matches in a list context, but you are using it in a scalar context. In a scalar context, the match operator returns a Boolean that indicates whether the match was successful or not. Therefore you get `1`. You can use

```
my ($t) = $line =~ m/(\[.*\])/;
```

to create a list context, or you can use `$1` instead of using `$t`.

Comment: Not so.  `=~` returns an array *in a list context*, which is not the case here.  `print` is called in a void context in the OP's code, and does not force scalar interpretation of array arguments — and there aren't any of those anyway.  The OP cannot "try `$t[0]`" unless there is a `@t`.

Comment: @pilcrow Now it looks right? I didn't have much perl experience other than read the first few chapters of `Learning Perl`.

Comment: @pilcrow. It never returns an array. It's impossible to return an array. Only lists of scalars can be returned.

Answer (score 2):

Use parentheses around `$t`:

```
($t) = $line =~m/(\[.*\])/;
```

Refer to [perldoc perlretut (Extracting matches)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Extracting-matches).

I believe you are using the match operator (`m//`) in a scalar context and storing the result in `$t`.  Since the match is successful, `m//` returns 1.  Refer to [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).